# Vim displaying incorrect colors inside tmux

Tags: vim, tmux, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have Ubuntu 17.04, Tmux: 2.3, vim:8.0, and a colorscheme called onedark

Vim displays right colorscheme when i am **not** inside TMUX, but when i am **inside** TMUX, vim looks completely different.

I tired every possible configurations in my .bashrc, .vimrc and .tmux.conf, but no luck.
I just recently discovered that when i run vim inside Tmux with sudo, root(administrative) privileges, everything works as expected which i don't think is a good solution.

So my question is how can i make vim display consistent colorscheme regardless of root privilages or weather i am inside or outside of Tmux.

My configurations related to colors are.

**.tmux.conf**

```
set-option -sa terminal-overrides ",xterm*:Tc"
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
```

**.vimrc**

```
set encoding=utf-8
set nocompatible 
set t_Co=256
set t_ut=
set background=dark
set showmatch
syntax on

if (empty($TMUX))

  if (has("nvim"))
    let $NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_TRUE_COLOR=1
  endif

  if (has("termguicolors"))
    set termguicolors
  endif

endif

colorscheme one
```

if do `echo $TERM` inside or outside of tmux, i get `xterm-256color`

Comment: Perhaps the culprit is the `termguicolors` settings that you enable in terminal but not Tmux?

Comment: Thans @AlexanderBatischev i was able to move the termguicolors from the IF condition and now things work fine.

Comment: Glad to hear that! I now posted my comment as an answer; please accept it.

Comment: @AlexanderBatischev Absolutely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit is the `termguicolors` setting which you enable in terminal but not Tmux. Moving it out of the outermost `if` should fix things.